# SQL Agent Command Line Not Saved

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have a SSIS package I am trying to schedule. I create a new job under SQL Server Agent. On the Command line tab of the jobstep, I choose "Edit the command-line manually".

The changes are retained as I switch from tab to tab within the job step but whenever I exit and save the job, the changes are lost.

Any ideas what's going on?

I'm on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug, but here's a workaround that my team uses:

1) Script the create job statement (without your edits)

2) Delete the job from SQL Agent

3) Perform your edits in the create script

4) Execute the create job

This will allow you to keep your manually modified command line options.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with the Set Values properties in SQL Server Agent for SSIS packages. You need to save the job step while still on the tab I think(?). I'll see if I can remember and reproduce the steps, but you're not going crazy. ;)

You may need to click "OK" for the job step, and "OK" for the job before moving on to any other changes in the job.

Comment: I just tried clicking OK while I'm on the tab but it didn't help.  Is there another workaround?

Comment: I'm going from memory, but I think that it had something to do with the client SSMS not being the same version as the server. I have some notes on it at home, so I'll try to remember to post back here tonight when I have them in hand.

Comment: Thanks.  That would be great if you could post your notes.  We do have SQL2000 and SQL2008 installed on this machine.  I wonder if that's related somehow?

Comment: It looks like invalid command line entries get reverted, although I was able to save successfully with a valid entry. Can you post your before and after command lines?

Answer (score 1):

try a copy save as on the package and save change the protection level to encrypt sensitive data with password

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to append /DumpOnError to the command line tab of the only step in a job. What I realized was that the change was really performed. And I found it out by generating the "create job" script. What was happening then? Well, it seems as if in the edit box of the command line tab you always got the "default" configuration, however the real one is. I checked it on three installations. 2008 standard, 2012 enterprise and 2017 enterprise.